# approximation of function by Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

Assume we have a function:
$$
f(x) = (1+x)^{k}
$$
with a fixed integer $k$. Next, let us approximate $f(x)$ by Taylor series around $0$:
$$
f(x) = 1 + kx + \frac{1}{2}k(k-1)x^{2} + o(x^{2}).
$$

Next, let us take some fixed small $x$. Would it make sense to consider the function $f$ as a function of $k$ and write
$$
f(k) \approx 1 + (x-\frac{1}{2}x^{2})k + \frac{1}{2}x^{2}k^{2}
$$
?

PS I know that there is multivariate version of Taylor series, I am just confused with this approach.

Comment: If you do Taylor diectly for $k$, you have $$
(1 + x)^k  \approx 1 + k\log (1 + x) + k^2 \frac{{\log ^2 (1 + x)}}{2}.
$$ Now if you approximate the $\log$'s by Taylor polynomials, you obtain your final result. This shows that your result is useful only when both $x$ and $k$ are close to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I see.. Is there any way to find an approximation for "moderate" $k$, but small small $x$?

Comment: If $\left| x \right| \ll \frac{1}{{\left| k \right|}}$ then your original Taylor approximation is a good approximation.